# Type in a shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

So I'm trying to recreate a cover for a single, and I've got most of it down except for one part. There's a piece of text contained inside a circle-type shape that I can't quite seem to get down. I've tried type on a path but it doesn't work as I want it to, since the text seems to go **inside** the shape.

Check out the attached pic to see what I'm trying to get at. Any ideas? Thanks :)

[image: It Can Happen logo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This image is taken from the cover of about 26 years old record of band YES. I guess you can legally draw a copy only for watching it alone in your home.

But that was not the problem. Stretching and rotating your image until it was straight and round again and memorizing the numbers formed the following receipe:

[image]

1. Draw three cirles with diameters 50, 75 and 100 millimeters. The green one is just in the halfway of the red and blue ones, otherwise the exact millimeters are meaningless. Align them to the same center. Draw from the center a vertical line and make plus and minus 27,5 degrees rotated copies.
2. Split The circles at the crossings of the rotated lines. Remove the 55 degrees wide top sector
3. Write the text with the Type on Path tool on the green arc (=on center). Stretch the letter spacing in the Type > Character panel until the text fills the space. When the text seems to be evenly distributed outline it.
4. Select all, squeeze the shape horizontally to about 46% of the original width
5. Rotate the shape minus 18 degrees. Fill the space between the arcs with the Shape Builder or join the splitted arcs to get a colorable shape under the text.

The problematic "seem to go inside" is caused by the horizontal squeezing (4), I guess. It makes the gap between the letters and the arcs narrower at "C" and "P", but it doesn't affect the space above and under "H".

Answer (score -2):

You may do something like following. Get rectangle and text on it and then group them together by selecting both and `ctrl + g`

[image]

Then with above group selected go to

Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Wrap (or `alt + shift + ctrl + w` )

[image]

Adjust approximate settings to make arch and enter. Once your shape is extended, you can just use Direct Selection (`A`) tool to edit the nodes and make your desired shape by adjusting curves.

Here is rough manipulation I did. You can do even fine tuned if you want.

[image]

In the same set of options, you can do make it `with mesh` and can get even more fine tuned options.